# Crop an image in tikz using 2 points of reference and a height

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, scaling, crop, tikz-pic

Consider the following code:

```
% DOCUMENT TYPE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage[listings,skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% PRESENTATION
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

% DOCUMENT BEGINNING
\begin{document}
\lipsum~{}
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\lipsum
\end{document}
% DOCUMENT END
```

Which uses the image available [here](http://magnatiles.com/wp-content/uploads/valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg).

The result will be the following:
[image]

Now is the tricky part. I want to cut the image in the following way :

- the top left corner should start from 200px horizontally and 100px vertically from the top left corner ot the original image
- the top right corner should start from 400px horizontally and 100px vertically from the top left corner ot the original image
- the resulting image should be resized to the entire page width
- the image should be cut so that its height is 4cm

Here is the part of the image I want to import (pagewidth here means `\paperwidth`):

[image]

So that the final result will be:

[image]

How to do that?

Note: this is an "academic" exercise so I understand how to do that and be able to cut other figures with other lengths/scales in the same way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Package `adjustbox`

Your preamble already contains package `adjustbox`. It provides the features you need for trimming and clipping

I am not sure, which spacing is needed around the image. The following example lets the image behave as it would have the height of the upper case letter `H` and the depth of `g`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]

\centerline{%
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{H}%
  \adjincludegraphics[
    Clip={\dimexpr\width*200/2048\relax}
         {0pt}
         {\dimexpr\width*400/2048\relax}
         {\dimexpr\height*100/1356\relax},
    width=\paperwidth,
    Clip={0pt} {\dimexpr\height-4cm\relax} {0pt} {0pt},
    raise=\dimexpr\dimen0-\height\relax,
  ]{valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg}%
}
\settodepth{\prevdepth}{g}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Pixel sizes with package `bmpsize-base`

The common TeX compilers do not know anything about the pixel sizes of included images, even if the image format is supported.
Project `bmpsize` uses a (mode-independent) feature of pdfTeX, `\pdffiledump`, to parse and analyze the binary image bitmap files. Also LuaTeX is automatically supported Via package `pdftexcmds`. Package `bmpsize` adds support for image size detection for DVI drivers, unneeded for pdfTeX in PDF mode. But the image width and pixel width detection is outsourced in package `bmpsize-base`. The following example checks the supported image bitmap formats to get the pixel width and height:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{bmpsize-base}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\newcommand*{\imgfile}{valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getpixelsizes}[1]{%
  \expandafter\comma@parse\expandafter{\bmpsize@types}{%
    \csname bmpsize@read@\comma@entry\endcsname{#1}%
    \ifbmpsize@ok
      \let\PixelWidth\bmpsize@pixelwidth
      \let\PixelHeight\bmpsize@pixelheight
      \PackageInfo{ImageSize}{%
        File = #1\MessageBreak
        Size = \PixelWidth\space x \PixelHeight\space pixels\@gobble
      }%
      \comma@break
    \fi
    \@gobble
  }%
  \ifbmpsize@ok
  \else
    \PackageError{ImageSize}{%
      Cannot get pixel sizes for image file\MessageBreak
      `#1'%
    }\@ehc
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]

\centerline{%
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{H}%
  \getpixelsizes{\imgfile} 
  \adjincludegraphics[
    Clip={\dimexpr\width*200/\PixelWidth\relax}
         {0pt}
         {\dimexpr\width*400/\PixelWidth\relax}
         {\dimexpr\height*100/\PixelHeight\relax},
    width=\paperwidth,
    Clip={0pt} {\dimexpr\height-4cm\relax} {0pt} {0pt},
    raise=\dimexpr\dimen0-\height\relax,
  ]{\imgfile}%
}
\settodepth{\prevdepth}{g}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

## Without `adjustbox`

- The trimming can be done by option `trim` for `\includegraphics`. Since the unit is pixels, the pixel width and pixel height should be known.
  The actual calculation can be done by e-TeX's `\dimexpr` with high accuracy.
- Scaling to `\paperwidth` can be done by option `width`.
- The clipping to 4cm can be done by `tikz`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]

\centerline{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, baseline=-height("H")]
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (\paperwidth, -4cm);
    \node[below right] (img) {%
      \sbox0{\includegraphics{valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg}}%
      \includegraphics[
        trim={\dimexpr\wd0*200/2048\relax}
             {0pt}
             {\dimexpr\wd0*400/2048\relax}
             {\dimexpr\ht0*100/1356\relax},
       width=\paperwidth,
      ]{valtech-magna-tiles-tessellation-hexagons-2048x1356.jpg}%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\kern-4cm
\nointerlineskip
\vbox to 4cm{\vphantom{g}}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: With a so complete solution I'll delete mine. Nice!

Comment: Your second example does not compile (missing "}") or wrong sbox0 line?

Comment: @Vincent Simple copy&paste error, fixed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Last question: how to have the 2048 and 1356 (in the division) directly computed by latex and not put by hand.

Comment: @Vincent The updated answer contains a variant with the detection of pixel width and height via package `bmpsize-base`.